# Strange output for function with variable number parameters of type double

Tags: c++, c

I tried function with variable number of integer parameters, it worked as expected. But when I tried variable number of parameters of type "double",  it gave strange output:

```
$ g++ -fpermissive -std=c++11 te2d.cc
te2d.cc: In function ‘void maxof(double, long int, ...)’:
te2d.cc:19:16: warning: return-statement with a value, in function returning 'void' [-fpermissive]
$ ./a.out
dum=100.200000
debug 1 0.000000
debug 2 0.000000
debug 3 -5486124068793688683255936251187209270074392635932332070112001988456197381759672947165175699536362793613284725337872111744958183862744647903224103718245670299614498700710006264535590197791934024641512541262359795191593953928908168990292758500391456212260452596575509589842140073806143686060649302051520512.000000
debug 4 0.000000
```

Here is the short code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
typedef unsigned char uchar;
typedef unsigned short uint16;
using namespace std;
typedef unsigned char uchar;
void maxof(double dum, long n_args, ...){
        printf("dum=%f\n", dum);
        register int i;
        int max = 0;
        va_list ap;

        va_start(ap, n_args);
        for(i = 1; i <= n_args; i++) {
            printf("debug %d %f\n", i, va_arg(ap, double));
        }

        va_end(ap);
        return max;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    maxof(100.2, 4, 10,14,13,11);
    return 0;
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: In my experiences, `-fpermissive` is a terrible flag to include. Why are you trying to return a value from a function that returns nothing? And sticking `register` on that variable declaration is unlikely to help you in any way.

Comment: `maxof(100.2, 4, 10,14,13,11);` for the last 4 parameters you are passing integers but in the processing you are expecting `double`. That is your main problem I think.

Comment: Thanks @chris.  Agree with your point.

Comment: You're passing `int`, but then you're not telling the truth in your `maxof` function and saying that they're `double`.  Undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks @michael-petch, that did it.  I changed the numbers in the function call to be double and it worked ok. I had thought compiler will automatically convert them to double.   Could you write an answer so it can be accepted?

Comment: @paulmckenzie,  I thought compiler will do the conversion like it does for `double x = 1;`

Comment: @codingFun - When you use variadic functions, you must tell the compiler what the argument types are that are being retrieved.  If you want an example, look how `printf` works -- it uses a format string that specifies the parameter types, and if your format string lies to printf, all havoc breaks loose.

Comment: Good point @paulmckenzie.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C variadic functions don't magically handle conversions from `int` to `double`*. You need to specify the type that went into the function, not the type you want to end up with after conversions. Think of it as telling the compiler how to interact with the stack. If you tell it the top of the stack has a `double` and `double` is bigger than `int`, you've now just told it to take extra bytes off of the stack, which is terrible. Even if they were the same size, they do not have the same binary representation.

You really have to be careful with C variadic functions. The better solution, if available, would be to use variadic templates, which are perfectly typesafe and trigger *compile-time* errors rather than undefined behaviour. In this case, since you want all arguments to be the same type, you can use `std::initializer_list`:

```
#include <initializer_list> //be sure not to forget this when using std::initializer_list

double maxof(std::initializer_list<double> nums) {
    double max = 0; //hope you don't have negative numbers
    for (const auto &num : nums) {
        if (num > max) {max = num;}
    }

    return max;
}

...

maxof({10,14,13,11})
```

Note that there's an overload of `std::max` that does this, so no need to write your own.

If you're stuck with pre-C++11, you could potentially create many overloads to get the same effect, but you'd be much better off creating a function based on a container or iterators, like `std::max_element`.

---

*Promotions are applied to arguments, so it's not always the exact type that goes in. For example, passing in a `char` will require the function to extract an `int`. These promotions are well-specified and are mostly `<small integral type>` -> `int`.

Comment: Thanks @chris for good explanation and especially the snippet.